# How to make sure "brew" only installs what I want without breaking other things?

Tags: homebrew

On a Mac 12.4 I just wanted to install a package named `gdb` to try to see if that fixes a problem, so I choose to use the command

```
brew install gdb
```

but instead it seem to have updated all other packages (and it did not solve the problem).
It also updated `mplayer` which then was broken.

Is there a way to isolate or pin versions using brew tools if I detect an issue with everything being fully updated?

Comment: This has nothing to do with macOS.  It is a brew design decision to update everything.

Comment: Is there any way I can tell brew not to update certain applications, like `mplayer`?

Comment: Alex, I’ve edited your question a bit. The Mac solution to this is time machine backups. When you make an update that breaks things, roll back to the snapshot from an hour ago and then you can pick a more surgical install option. Brew lets you install older versions, so you might just need to keep track of which versions worked to install a down-level **mplayer** - Dependency management is hard having a backup you can easily restore makes it less burdensome to test every change you make

Comment: How did you install mplayer?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a `brew` option to do so?

For pinning a formula to a specific version, there is [`brew pin`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#pin-installed_formula-):

> ## `pin` *`installed_formula`* `[…]`
>
> Pin the specified *`formula`*, preventing them from being upgraded when issuing the `brew upgrade` *`formula`* command. See also `unpin`.

Note that [the documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/) only specifically talks about `brew upgrade`, but one would assume that the automatic upgrading as part of `brew install` is covered as well.

In the past, there was a `brew switch` command to toggle between two versions of the same package to assist in managing dependencies. You can get that back now with `brew tap mistydemeo/cmd`